# Chained selects and form element switching

Tags: jquery, forms, select, internationalization, chained

My company, located in the US, ships to the US and Canada. We accept billing, however, from all over the world. In our shipping/billing form redesign, I am working with chained selects so that when the user selects his shipping country, the state list and the zip/postal code field both change appropriately.

I want to do the same thing with billing, but it is a little more complicated. Not only do the state and postal code boxes need to change, but the phone text input needs to change, too. The state dropdown need to change to a text input as well, and I need to add a text field for county.

I'm trying to keep these two aspects plus payment in one form; inline validation to guide the user and backend validation are both coming.

I can get the state list and postal code boxes to change and change back appropriately, but when I add the select/text input swap, or the phone input swap (or all three), the script fails completely. In my jsfiddle, I have some commented out jQuery with the direction I was thinking. What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

My code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/LqggY/8/.

NOTE: my backend devs don't know much front end code (plus, there's a language barrier), so I'd like to keep things as simple as possible for them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note: Canada doesn't have states. It has provinces! You need to update the label of the dropdown :)

Comment: Adjusted - thanks for the reminder!